# Getting limited random node values

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm looking for a way to get a random value between 2 given integers.

**As an example:**

In this particular case I need to get a random blackbody value that's between *3000(min)* and *5500(max)*.
[image]

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved with some (for my level) clever use of the math node:

[image: Node setup]

A quick rundown of what the nodes do in this case:

Subtract: calculates the difference between your desired minimum and maximum value. In other words, the maximum amount of variation that could happen, in this case 2500.

Multiply: Multiplies the previous calculated value with the output from the Random value of the Object Info node, which lies between 0 and 1. This creates a random value between, in this case, 0 and 2500.

Add: Adds the randomly generated value of the Multiply node to the mininum value you have specified, resulting in a random number which cannot go below your desired minimum or above your desired maximum.

In this case what happens is: 
3000 + value between 0 and 2500 = value between 3000 and 5500

(No i do not know the proper math symbols, but I think you get the point.)

Result:

[image: Result]